# Error retrieving a value from DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to retrieve the value for a WPF DataGrid cell for DataGrid Helper class, but I get the following error:

> Unable to convert system.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell to String

If cell value is 90 I am getting Below Value

> system.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell 90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your code, anyway, I try. Have you tried to insert this?

```
MyDataGridCell.Content
```

This should return to you the content of the cell.

If you have still problems, post your code.